# Frame Offset for Histogram/Vectorgram in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to colour match two different video clips within Blender VSE.
I've opened up two preview windows and have applied a frame offset to one of them to be able to look at two different clips at the same time.
I have tried to do the same thing for a pair of vectorscope windows, so that I can more accurately compare the colour, but they both seem to display the information for the current frame and not the offset frame, despite setting up the frame offset correctly.
Is there any way to correct this, or should I make a bug report/feature request?

Comment: What version of Blender are you using as the Frame Offset function for preview does not seem to be available in 2.8?

Comment: I'm using 2.82 on Linux. Frame offset is definitely working correctly on the preview windows but not on the histogram etc.